# Cancel Datetimepicker ValueChanged Event

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to cancel an event through a condition? I have tried `e.cancel` but it does not work. After cancelling the event the `dtpAudit_From.Value` must revert back to its original value.

```
Private Sub dtpAudit_From_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dtpAudit_From.ValueChanged
        'check if two DTPs (Date time pickers) are valid
        If dtpAudit_From.Value > dtpAudit_To.Value Then
            MsgBox("cancel the event")

        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: store value in a variable, and then extract it at the time of cancelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to subclass the `DateTimePicker` and add a `ValueChanging` event. Here's an example:

```
Public Class UIDateTimePicker
    Inherits DateTimePicker

    Public Sub New()
        Me.cachedValue = Me.Value
    End Sub

    Public Event ValueChanging As CancelEventHandler

    Protected Overrides Sub OnValueChanged(e As EventArgs)
        If (Not Me.reverting) Then
            Dim evargs As New CancelEventArgs(False)
            Me.OnValueChanging(evargs)
            If ((Not evargs Is Nothing) AndAlso evargs.Cancel) Then
                Dim value As Date = Me.Value
                Me.reverting = True
                Me.Value = Me.cachedValue
            Else
                Me.cachedValue = Value
                MyBase.OnValueChanged(e)
            End If
            Me.reverting = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnValueChanging(e As CancelEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ValueChanging(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Private cachedValue As DateTime
    Private reverting As Boolean

End Class
```

**Usage**

```
Private Sub dtpAudit_From_ValueChanging(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles dtpAudit_From.ValueChanging
    e.Cancel = {Condition}
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried the code, but it says `Event "ValueChanging" cannot be found".. I made a new winforms project, inserted the code in the form1 class, then added a datetimepicker, pasted the usage code (i changed the control's name to the default, datetimepicker1).

Comment: Create a new class file, paste my code, and rebuild yor project. Then when you open the form, drag the UIDateTimePicker (now visible at the top of the toolbox pane) onto your form.